# How to integrate the following geometric brownian motion in Black-Scholes framework

Tags: brownian-motion, finance

As my previous questions make it obvious, I am very new to this field of mathematics and wondering if I am doing things right in the following question.

> Let $T \in (0, \infty)$ and consider a Black-Scholes market for a stock $(S_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$(A geometric Brownian motion with drift $r$ and volatility $\sigma$). Consider the *all or nothing option* contract with the payoff at time $T$ defined by
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{cc}
>   g(x)=\{ & 
>     \begin{array}{cc}
>       P & \text{ if }x \geq K \\
>       0 & \text{ if } x< K
>     \end{array}
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> where $P>0,K>0$ are given real constants. Compute the price $\Pi(0;g(S_T))$ of the contract $g(S_T)$. Namely, find the expression of $\Pi(0;g(S_T))|_{S_0}=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)]$

My attempt was simply find $e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)]$. So, for the $\mathbb{E}$ bit, I need to calculate

$$\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)]=\int_K^\infty S_T \cdot P\cdot dS_T$$

(I am not sure if this $dS_T$ i.e. integrate wrp to $S_T$ is correct or not) which is due to the general definition of a continuous random variable expected value $\mathbb{E}[x]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$. But I am not sure how to proceed, i.e. how to integrate this geometric brownian motion...wrp to a geoertic brownian motion(which yes, sounds wrong actually...).

It would be great if someone can guide me here, I hope my basic attempt overall shouldn't be entirely wrong. I think I am not very sure about the details.

Would someone please help me? It would be great if I can get some explanations in the details along rather than just a brief answer, sorry for asking a lot. Thank you very much in advance

*Update*

I have made some progress hopefully, so please tell me if it looks okay or not.
I have seen that, given some random variable $X$, with pdf $f(x)$, the expected value of a new variable $Y=g(x)$ for some function $g$ is $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)dx$. I have based my calculations on this.\

So in my case,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)] &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(S_T:=x)f(S_T:=x)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{K}0f(x)dx+\int_{K}^{\infty}Pf(x)dx$\\
\end{align*}

Now since my $S_T$, a geometric brownian motion is lognormally distributed with mean $S_0e^{rt}$ and variance $S_0^2e^{2rt}(e^{\sigma^2t}-1)$, I will substitute these in to the PDF of a lognormal function as my $f(x)$. So,

$$\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)] = \frac{1}{S_0e^{rt} \sqrt{2 \pi(e^{\sigma^2 t}-1)}} \int_{K}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}e^{- \frac{(lnx-S_0e^{rt})^2}{2S_0^2e^{2rt}(e^{\sigma^2t}-1)}} dx$$

It looks ugly, so I did an interchange of variables introducing $z=lnx-S_0e^{rt}$. Thus I have $x$ from $K \rightarrow \infty|$ then $z$ from $lnK-S_0e^{rt} \rightarrow \infty$ and $dx = e^{z+S_0e^{rt}}dz$. So substituting these, I get something better,

$$\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)] = \frac{1}{S_0e^{rt} \sqrt{2 \pi(e^{\sigma^2 t}-1)}} \int_{lnK-S_0e^{rt}}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{z^2}{c}}dz$$

where $c=2S_0^2e^{2rt}(e^{\sigma ^2t}-1)$

My question is, the integral now involves (Gauss') error function which is well, complicated. I can fortunately compute the error function's value for the one up to $\infty$ which is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ I think but not for the one up to $lnK-S_0e^{rt}$. All I can think of is expressing it as a Taylor expansion of the error function.

But is this correct? This is the best I can do so far...

Please please help! Thank you again.

Comment: What happened to the probability density function under the integral?  Replace $S_T$ with the lognormal PDF.  The, the integral can be written in terms of the Cumulative Normal Function (related to the error function).  It is the $N(d_2)$ term in the Black-Scholes-Merton formula.  Note that the value is the discounted probability of expiring in the money.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping; yes I noticed after I posted that it's odd to miss a $f(x)$ in the integral. So the integral is $\int_K^\infty P \cdot \frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}  e^ {      - \frac {(lnx- \mu)^2}  {2 \sigma^2}     } dx$? is this with respect to $dx$?

Comment: That isn't quite correct unless your $mu$ becomes $$\mu =\left(r-\delta-\frac12 \sigma^2\right)(T-t)$$and the $\sigma$ that currently appears in your expression in the comment is replaced with $\sigma\sqrt{T-t}$, where $r$ is the risk-free rate, $\delta$ a continuous yield, $T-t$ is the time remaining from $t$ to expiry at $T$

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I got what you've told me there...but I've made my update based on what I understood from you. If you do have the time, it would be great if you would kindly look into it...thank you so much

Comment: It does not look correct.  If you use the density function that you wrote, corrected as per my previous note, then you should be fine.

Comment: alright, so the density function is correct, BUT i must replace the mean $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the original function with $\mu=(r-\delta-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)$ (what is $\delta$ though? It does not appear in my given variables/parameters) and $\sigma$ with $\sigma \sqrt{T-t}$ and proceed with the integration?

Comment: *ohps, I didn't see the "continuous yield for $\delta$ in your previous comment; I'm not sure what that is though...Is it equivalent to the continuous interest rate?

Comment: The yield can account for a continuous dividend yield, the risk-free rate when the underlying is a futures/forward price, or a foreign interest rate when the underlying is the spot exchange rate of currency.

Comment: Okay, so for a final check; is this what you are saying then? $\mathbb{E}[g(S_T)]= \int_K^{\infty} P \frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi(T-t)}}e^ { -  \frac{(lnx -(r-\delta -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t))^2}{2\sigma^2(T-t)}     }  dx$ this is what I must calculate? I replaced the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ with those in your second comment...

Comment: That looks correct now! Note $P$ is constant and pulls out of the integral.

Comment: Right, thank you so much. As in my edited version, if I proceed with the integration, I end up having to integrate $\frac{P}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi (T-t)}}\int_{lnK-(r-\delta-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2 \sigma^2(T-t)}}dz$  where I've used $z=e^{z+(r-\delta-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}$. The integration of $e^{-\frac{z^2}{c}}$ is a problem unless I can integrate from $-\infty,\infty$ or $0,\pm\infty$...is there something you would suggest? Because I have to integrate from $lnK-(r-\delta-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t), \infty$...

Comment: The answer can be expressed in terms of the Cumulative Normal Function (or the Error Function if one prefers).

Comment: I'm sorry this is getting so long; if so, my answer becomes $$\frac{P\sqrt{\pi 2 \sigma^2(T-t)}}{2 \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi(T-t)}} (1 - erf[\frac{lnK-(r-\delta-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sqrt{2 \sigma^2(T-t)}}])$$ which looks quite complicated, but if I may leave my answer in terms of the error function, I think this is the simplest form I can leave it in...If my previous integral with $z$ is correct, I believe this is where I end up...

Answer (score 1):

You have the right start in that you want to compute
$$
e^{-rT}E_Q(g(S_T))
$$
where $Q$ is the risk-neutral probability measure and, under $Q$,
$$
S_T = S_0e^{\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma W_T}.
$$
So we have 
$$
e^{-rT}E_Q(g(S_T)) = e^{-rT}E_Q(P\cdot \mathbb{I}_{S_T \geq K}) = Pe^{-rT}Q(S_T \geq K),
$$
where the last equality is because
$$
E_Q(\mathbb{I}_{S_T \geq K}) = Q(S_T \geq K).
$$
A simplifying step often done in texts is to use only the normal distribution, instead of the more cumbersome lognormal, as follows.  Note
\begin{align}
S_T \geq K & \iff S_0e^{\left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma W_T} \geq K \\
& \iff \left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma W_T \geq \log \frac{K}{S_0} \\
& \iff W_T \geq \frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\log\frac{K}{S_0} - \left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T\right) \\
& \iff \frac{W_T}{\sqrt{T}} =: Z  \geq \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}\left(\log\frac{K}{S_0} - \left(r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T\right) =: -d_2.
\end{align}
Note I'm suggestively calling the RHS $-d_2$, and $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  Hence, letting $\phi$ be the standard normal pdf and $\Phi$ the standard normal cdf,
\begin{align}
Pe^{-rT}Q(S_T \geq K) & = Pe^{-rT}Q(Z \geq -d_2) \\
& = Pe^{-rT}\int_{-d_2}^\infty \phi(x)\, dx \\
& = Pe^{-rT}\int_{-\infty}^{d_2}\phi(x)\, dx \\
& = Pe^{-rT}\Phi(d_2).
\end{align}